# STM32 handmade USART driver

Tags: microcontroller, uart, stm32, cortex-m, bit-bang

I designed a new electronic card which has a STM32F4 microcontroller on it. Each peripheral except the Wifi module works. Wifi module is supposed to communicate with the controller via USART channel but I failed to connect RX/TX pins to a USARTx module of the controller. So in brief, the RX/TX pins are connected to simple GPIO pins by mistake. I don't want to modify the electronic card and make it reproduced, it will cost me a lot.

The question is can I write a homemade USART driver for a STM32F4 microcontroller in order to communicate with the Wifi module with using 2 GPIOs (1 for RX and 1 for TX)? I did it many years ago for I2C but I'm not sure if it can be possible for USART.

Comment: Search for bitbanging. It is ceraintly possible with UART as well, Arudino uses software serial solutions too.

Comment: [stm32duino software serial implementation](https://github.com/wingspinner/SoftSerialIntAP)

Comment: What bit rate is needed?

Comment: I need 115200 and/or below.

Answer (score 2):

Running at 168 MHz, you'd have 1458 clock cycles between two consecutive bits at 115200 bps, that seems to be enough for the processing, but a bit tight for the output accuracy, see below.

Output is straightforward if you have a free timer, set it to generate an interrupt at the bitrate frequency, and shift out the start bit, data bits, stop bit in the interrupt routine. This interrupt must have the highest possible priority to achieve 5% accuracy, which is just 72 cycles. Put your stack and relevant variables in the CCM memory, vector table and interrupt routine in the internal SRAM, and disable saving floating point registers, to minimize interrupt latency. Read [this ARM FAQ](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka16366.html) for the implications.

If your RX pin can be mapped to a timer input, do that. You can program the timer to generate an interrupt on both edges, it can be filtered by hardware, and you get a timestamp stored in the capture register, so you can determine the exact time when the edge arrived, even when the interrupt is delayed a bit.